# Python list of lists no loops

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, readlines

So full disclosure, this is hw, but I am having a lot of difficulty figuring this out. My professor has a rather particular challenge in this one portion of the assignment that I can't quite seem to figure out. Basically I'm trying to read a very very large file and put it into a list of lists that's represented as a movie recommendation matrix. She says that this can be done without a for loop and suggests using the readlines() method.

I've been running this code:

```
movMat = []
with open(u"movie-matrix.txt", 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as f:
    movMat.append(f.readlines())
```

But when I run diff on the output, it is not equivalent to the original file. Any suggestions for how I should go about this?

Update: upon further analysis, I think my code is correct. I added this to make it a tuple.

```
with open(u"movie-matrix.txt", 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as f:
movMat = list(enumerate(f.readlines()))
```

Update2: Since people seem to want the file I'm reading from, allow me to explain. This is a ranking system from 1-5. If a person has not ranked a file, they are denoted with a ';'. This is the second line of the file.

"3;;;;3;;;;;;;;3;;;;;;;;;2;;;;;;;;3;;;;;;;;;;;;5;;;;;;;1;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;3;;;;;;;;3;;;;;;;;;;;4;;;;4;;;;;3;;;2;;;;;;;2;;;;;;;;3;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;4;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;4;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;3;;;;3;;;4;2;;;;;;3;;;;;;4;;;;3;;;;;3;;;;;;;;;;;;2;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;3;4;;;;;;5;;;;;;;;;;;3;2;;;1;;;;;4;;;4;3;;;;;;;;;;;;4;3;;;;;;;;2;;3;;2;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;4;;;;;1;;2;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;5;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;4;;;;;;;;;;4;4;;;;2;3;;;;;;3;;4;;;;;;4;;;;;3;3;;;;;;1;;4;;;;;;;;;4;;;;;;;;;2;;;;3;;;;;;4;;;;;;;3;;;;;;;;4;;;;;4;;;;;;;;;;;1;;;;;;5;;;;;;;;;;;;4;;;3;;;;;;;;2;;1;;;;;;;;;4;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;3;;;;;;;;;;;5;;;;4;;;;;;;3;;;;;;;;2;;;;;;;;;;3;;;;;5;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;3;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;2;;;3;4;;;;;3;;;;;4;;;;;;;;4;;4;3;;;;;4;;3;;;1;;3;;;;;2;;;;;;;;;;;4;;;;;;;;;;;3;;;;3;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;3;;;;4;;;;;;3;;;;;;;;;;;;4;;;;;;;;;;;3;;;;;;;;3;;;4;;4;;;;;;3;;;;;;;3;;;;;;;;;3;1;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;3;;;;;3;5;;4;;;;;;4;;3;4;;;;;;;;3;;;;;;;;;;;3;;;;3;;;;;;;;;;;;;;4;;5;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;4;;;;2;;2;;;;;;;;;;3;;;;;;4;;;3;;;4;;;;3;;;3;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;3;;;;;;;;3;;;;;;;;;;4;;;;;;;;;5"

Comment: What is the original file? What is the example input and expected output?

Comment: Looks like you might need to use `movMat.extend(f.readlines())` rather than `movMat.append(f.readlines())`. But we would need more information as Marcin states to say more.

Comment: Well...upon further analysis, I think the reason why diff is showing a difference is that the text isn't stretching as far as in the text file...in other words, my method does work.  Trust me when I say. You do not (And I don't think this site can handle properly in order to convey the information of the file) want this file on here.

Comment: Give us a couple lines at least...

Comment: alright. There you go :P

Comment: thankyou for full disclosure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of **any** case where `f.readlines()` would be better than just using `f` as an iterable.  That is, for example,

```
with open('movie-matrix.txt', 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as f:
    movMat = list(f)
```

(no reason using `u'...'` notation in Python 3 -- which you have to be using if built-in `open` takes `encoding=`...!-).

Yes, `f.readlines()` would be equivalent to `list(f)` -- but it's more verbose and less obvious, so, what's the **point**?!

Assuming you have to output this to another file, since you mention "running diff on the output", that would be

```
with open('other.txt', 'w', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as f:
    f.writelines(movMat)
```

no non-for-loop alternatives there:-).

Comment: I guess it's her way of being "pythonic"...but like I said...I believe that actually my solution works. I'm supposed to make a list of lists, and I suppose turn it into a tuple. This is my new code. 

    with open(u"movie-matrix.txt", 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as f:
    movMat = list(enumerate(f.readlines()))

Comment: Two uses of `readlines`: You can give it a size hint and it's likely to be a tiny bit faster than indirection through an iterable. I can't think of the last time I've ever cared (by that point just using `read` is normally better) but I'm sure somebody, somewhere, does.

Comment: Yeah. I'm not too big on it either. But points are points. :P